# How to call a function in another file in Scala?

Tags: scala

I am trying to figure out how to split up a scala program into multiple files.
My background is mostly C programming. I want to learn how to do the equivalent of C's `#include` in Scala.

I am trying as follows:

```
package test

object HelloObject {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    HelloTwoObject.foo()
  }
}
```

and in another file I have

```
package test

object HelloTwoObject {
  def foo(){
    println("Hello Foo!")
  }
}
```

Then I do `scalac hello.scala hellotwo.scala`

Then I go into the folder test and try `scala HelloObject.class`, but it doesn't work. It gives me a long error

What is wrong here?

Comment: This compiles for me. What is the error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scala executable takes a *script file* or an *object name* as an argument, but `HelloObject.class` is neither.

It should just be `scala test.HelloObject`.

Answer (score 0):

The specific issue in your case is the wrong compilation command, like @KimStebel said above.

But to answer your specific question:as long as both the files/functions/objects are within the same package,(which you are already doing, as `package test`) it will automatically link.